# Documents on a Windows 7 client connected to a Windows 2003 server's domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7

I have a Windows 7 client connected to a domain running on a Windows 2003 server.  The user's Word files are stored in the "Documents" folder under "Libraries".  Which I click on the "Documents" folder, the two location I see are "\server\home\username" and "C:\Users\Public\Documents" (with the former marked as the Default save location).

I'm trying to find out where the Word files are actually stored so that I can use Robocopy to copy it to the server.  To find the location, I did this:

1. I logged in as the user on a different machine (Win XP) - but could not see the Word files in the "My Documents" folder.
2. I unplugged the network cable and logged into the original Windows 7 computer - and was able to see and access the Word files in "Documents" folder.

The two steps above would indicate that the Word files is on the laptop somewhere.

I have tried these things:

1. I look in "C:\Users\Public\Documents" folder, but I don't see any Word files.
2. I look in "C:\Users\domain.username" folder, but I don't see the "Documents" folder.  I see a "My Documents" shortcut and when I click on it, I get a "Location is not available" error message.
3. I look in "C:\Users\username" folder and I get a message saying that the user doesn't have permission to view the data.  So I enter my credentials and am able to log in.  I see:

   - a "My Documents" folder but it doesn't have the Word files for which I am looking
   - a "My Documents" shortcut but when I double-click it, I get a "Location is not available" error message

Here are my questions:

1. Where are the Word files?
2. How may I access it when I'm logged in as the user"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out which locations are being used for the Documents library, right click on the Documents folder *under libraries* and pull up the property sheet.  This has been bugging me for a while, and your question prompted me to find and read up on Libraries [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-7-libraries-%E2%80%93-and-why-you-want-them/).

Comment: Thanks, Kara!  The two locations are "\\server\home\username" and "C:\Users\Public\Documents".  But why can't I traverse to the actual files.  I wonder if I can't see it because of a GPO on the domain.  There are two GPOs on the domain (one has to do with 'Software Install' and the other has to do with 'User Logon Policy').  Thanks!

Comment: If you can't browse to the files, I'm going to suspect the folder needs either the correct file-level and/or share-level permissions.  Assuming you're heading to \\client\c$\users\public\documents ?

Comment: Windows 7 has some virtulization folders that are redirected for compatibility - explorer doesn't seem to follow those redirections.

Answer (score 1):

Charles:

Is your documents and profile path mapped correctly?

When you say login, do you mean as a network (AD user) or local user?

Comment: Hi, Kyle!  Great question.

Comment: Yes, I'm logged in as an AD user.  The profile path is blank and the 'Home folder' has 'Local path' selected, but there is nothing entered in the selection.  Thanks!

Comment: By nothing entered in the selection, I mean it is blank.